# discord.py SelectMenu in slash_command with SelectOption's

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to create a tree.command that is a slash_command, in the slash_comamnd the user can choose a SelectOption in a SelectMenu and if the SelectOption with the variable'hack' is choosen it shall send a response. The bot wont even start now because i get the TypeError: "'member_descriptor' object is not callable"
This is the script:

```
@tree.command(name='test', description='test', guild=discord.Object(12345678))
async def slash_command(interaction: discord.Interaction, reporttype: discord.SelectMenu(discord.SelectMenu.options(
    discord.SelectOption(label='Hacking', value='hack', description='did you experience someone hacking?'), 
    discord.SelectOption(label='Harassment', value='harass', description='did someone harass you?'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Discord ToS', value='tos', description='did you experience someone break the discord ToS in the server?'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Support', value='sup', description='do you need support?'))),
    name: discord.Member):
    if reporttype is discord.SelectOption(value='hack'):
        interaction.response('successfull')
```

im using this imports:

```
import discord
import discord.app_commands
import discord.ext
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
```

this is the variable for tree:

```
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)
```

i already tried this:

```
@tree.command(name='test', description='test', guild=discord.Object(12345678))
async def slash_command(interaction: discord.Interaction, reporttype: discord.SelectMenu.options(
    discord.SelectOption(label='Hacking', value='hack', description='did you experience someone hacking?'), 
    discord.SelectOption(label='Harassment', value='harass', description='did someone harass you?'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Discord ToS', value='tos', description='did you experience someone break the discord ToS in the server?'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Support', value='sup', description='do you need support?'))),
    name: discord.Member):
    if reporttype is discord.SelectOption(value='hack'):
        interaction.response('successfull')
```

but it doesnt works too

btw im kinda new in discord.py, i already asked a friend for help but he codes in hikari and lighblub and he couldnt help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a response you must use:

```py
await interaction.response.send_message('successfull')
```

I believe this is the error in your code. Additionally, I recommend that you use [Views](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view) to handle user interactions. I'll show you an example:

```py
HACK_OPTIONS = [
   discord.SelectOption(label='Hacking', value='hack', description='did you experience someone hacking?'),
   discord.SelectOption(label='Harassment', value='harass', description='did someone harass you?'),
   discord.SelectOption(label='Discord ToS', value='tos', description='did you experience someone break the discord ToS in the server?'),
   discord.SelectOption(label='Support', value='sup', description='do you need support?')
]

class HackView(discord.ui.View)
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(timeout=100)
   
   @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Please select an option", options=HACK_OPTIONS, max_values=1)
   async def reply_select(interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
      value = select.values[0]
      if value == 'hack':
         await interaction.responde.send_message("You selected hack!")
      else:
         await interaction.responde.send_message("You didn't select hack.")
```

With the view prepared, all you need to do is send it as a response to your command:

```py
@tree.command(name='test', description='test', guild=discord.Object(12345678))
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
   await interaction.response.send_message("I'm here to help you", view=HackView())
```

> Note: i haven't tested this code, but I hope it's working as expected.